# Is it possible to filter extjs charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, extjs4, extjs

Here's an example: I have a bar chart representing the status of my runs. I would like to make some sort of button or filter... so that I could change the range of the date. Ex: 1 day, 7 days, 30 days... etc. Is this even possible with an extjs chart? With grids it is, but I'm thinking something similar just with a chart. Something so that upon user selection, it sends the new date and changes the query.

Opinions, examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work in exactly the same way. Just call the appropriate methods (sort, filter, load) on the store and the chart will update.